# Changing mac address with cron

Tags: bash, cron, mac-address

I'm trying to change my MAC address by running a shell script in cron. Ubunutu 10.10.
Cron line:

```
40 16 * * * /root/proj/changeMAC.sh > /root/proj/log.txt
```

changeMAC.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.profile
. $HOME/.bashrc
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 hw ether XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
ifconfig eth0 up
dhclient eth0
```

Where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is a real MAC address. when this runs, the MAC address doesn't change. What gives?

Comment: Is there any output from the script?  I notice that you're not currently capturing `stderr` to `log.txt`; you may want to add `2>&1` onto the end of your crontab entry to also capture `stderr`.

Comment: Is `eth0` a physical device?  In general, you can't change the MAC because it's burned into the device.

Comment: Ahh I see. ifconfig and dhclient are not recognized as commands. What does this mean?

Comment: You'd also need to run network-configuration commands as root.  Verify them from the command line before trying from (the root or system) cron, and specify the full paths to the executables in the cron.

Answer (score 3):

`ifconfig` & `dhclient` are probably not in the usual PATH. Try using `/sbin/ifconfig` and `/sbin/dhclient`.